# Как программно сменить иконку у item?

Tags: android, menu, icon

Есть пункт меню item. Необходимо чтобы при нажатии на этот пункт менялась иконка этого пункта и после перезагрузки приложения сохраняла ту же самую иконку.
Как программно задать вроде понял:

```
item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_english_flag_24dp);
```

Но после нажатия на кнопку происходит recreate() чтобы поменялся язык интерфейса и я так понимаю меню заново перерисовывается из исходного xml.

Код меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_russian_flag_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/action_language"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/action_language"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/action_about"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Как можно сохранять нужное изображение  для иконки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сохраняйте, какую иконку нужно показать в `SharedPreferences`, и в `onCreateOptionsMenu()` выставляйте нужную иконкую

Чтобы найти нужный `MenuItem`, делайте так:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_language)
```

И дальше так, как вы и пытались:

```
item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_english_flag_24dp);
```

Comment: Можно немного подробнее о процессе выставления?
Я попытался добавить


   `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem item = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_language);

        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_english_flag_24dp);

        return true;

    }`


Но приложение при запуске выдает ошибку.

Comment: @АлександрТымчук, покажите XML меню. Для поиска элементов меню надо использовать не `findViewById`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_russian_flag_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/action_language"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/action_language"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/action_about"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>

Comment: @АлександрТымчук, добавьте код в вопрос, и отформатируйте, а я сейчас ответ напишу

Comment: @АлександрТымчук, обновил ответ.